# C++ Exception Minimax algorithm for Tictactoe

Tags: c++, artificial-intelligence, tic-tac-toe, minimax

I'm trying to make a simple AI for playing tictactoe, but it is not working; I get an 'std::out_of_range' when the board fills up (brute forcing till the first final nodes of the first branch), and I quite didn't find a solution.

If I play X at 0,0 it crashes on the return of the best move 
`return jogadas.at(melhorMov); // return best move` after the 10th iteration.

(full code for Windows MingW [here](https://bitbucket.org/angelorodem/tictactoe/overview) if you wish )

[image: Image of the error]

(the shown games above it's the bruteforcing steps, not the actual game)

AI algorithm:

1. Moving/launching AI

   ```
   void IA::movimenta(){ //lauches the AI move action
       std::cout << "**Pensando**" << std::endl; //little message
       pensamentos = 0;                          //counter of iterations
       cmp = campo.getcampo();                   //gets the pointer** to the tictactoe field
       AiMove jogada = MelhorJogada(AIjogador);  //gets the best move for the AIplayer
       campo.joga(AIjogador,jogada.x,jogada.y);  //puts the best move on the field
   }
   ```
2. Minimax Code

   ```
   #include "ia.h"
   #include <vector>
   #include <iostream>

   using namespace std;

   IA::IA()
   {

   }


   void IA::inicia(field &campo, field::jogador IAplayer){
       this->campo = campo;

       this->AIjogador = IAplayer;
       if(IAplayer == field::x){
           this->HUjogador = field::o;
       }else{
           this->HUjogador = field::x;
       }

   }


   void printacamp(field::campo **campo){
       cout << "  0 1 2" << endl;
       for (int var = 0; var < 3; ++var) {
           cout << var;
           cout << "|";
           for (int var2 = 0; var2 < 3; ++var2) {

               switch (campo[var][var2]) {
               case field::NADA:
                   cout << " ";
                   break;
               case field::x_c:
                   cout << "X";
                   break;
               case field::o_c:
                   cout << "O";
                   break;
               default:
                   break;
               }

               cout << "|";
           }
           cout << endl;
       }
   }

   void IA::movimenta(){ //lauches the AI move action
       std::cout << "**Pensando**" << std::endl; //little message
       pensamentos = 0;                          //couter of iterations
       cmp = campo.getcampo();                   //gets the pointer** to the tictactoe field
       AiMove jogada = MelhorJogada(AIjogador);  //gets the best move for the AIplayer
       campo.joga(AIjogador,jogada.x,jogada.y);  //puts the best move on the field
   }

   AiMove IA::MelhorJogada(field::jogador jogador){ //bruteforce through the possible moves and searches for the best one
       field::jogador vic = campo.checaJ(); // checks if someone wins the game (final node)
       if(vic == AIjogador){                //if AIplayer wins
           return AiMove(15);             //add 15 points
       } else if(vic == jogador){           //if human wins
           return AiMove(-15);            //add -15 points
       } else if(vic == field::NINGJ){      //if its a tie (full board no winners)
           return AiMove(0);               //score 0
       }                                  //if none of those, the game is still in progress
       std::vector<AiMove> jogadas;        //vector for moves, something tells me that it should be static but it gives alot of bugs and nosense moves (or no moves at all)
       AiMove jogada;                      //move for this iteration
       pensamentos++;                      //add counter
       cout << pensamentos << endl;        //print counter
       for (int y = 0; y < 3; ++y) {       //for each of the board
           for (int x = 0; x < 3; ++x) {
               if(cmp[x][y] == field::NADA){  // if its an empty space
                   jogada.x = x;              //gets the x,y of the empty space
                   jogada.y = y;
                   campo.jogaJ(jogador,jogada.x,jogada.y); //makes a move

                   printacamp(cmp);           //prints it on screen

                   if(jogador == AIjogador){  //if its max(AI) next is human
                       jogada.pontos = MelhorJogada(HUjogador).pontos;
                   }else{                     //if its min(Human) next is AI
                       jogada.pontos = MelhorJogada(AIjogador).pontos;
                   }
                   jogadas.push_back(jogada); //store the score of the final node
                   campo.jogaJ(field::NADAJ,jogada.x,jogada.y); // delete the move made for testings
               }
           }
       }
       int melhorMov = 0;                  // bestMove is 0
       if(jogador == AIjogador){           // if AIturn(max)
           int melhorPon = -1000000;       // best pontuation = -∞
           for (int var = 0; var < jogadas.size(); ++var) { //best move/points of the subbranches
               if(jogadas.at(var).pontos > melhorPon){
                   melhorMov = var;
                   melhorPon = jogadas.at(var).pontos;
               }
           }
       } else {                            //if human(min)
           int melhorPon = 1000000;        //best pontution = +∞
           for (int var = 0; var < jogadas.size(); ++var) { //best move/points of the subbranches
               if(jogadas.at(var).pontos < melhorPon){
                   melhorMov = var;
                   melhorPon = jogadas.at(var).pontos;
               }
           }
       }
       return jogadas.at(melhorMov); // return best move

   }
   ```
3. AI.h

   ```
   #pragma once
   #ifndef IA_H
   #define IA_H
   #include "field.h"
   #include <vector>
   struct AiMove {
       AiMove() {};
       AiMove(int Pontos) : pontos(Pontos) {}
       int x;
       int y;
       int pontos;
   };


   class IA
   {

   public:
           IA();
           void inicia(field &camp, field::jogador IAplayer);
           void movimenta();
   private:
           field campo;
           AiMove MelhorJogada(field::jogador HUjogador);
           field::campo **cmp;
           field::jogador HUjogador;
           field::jogador AIjogador;
           int pensamentos = 0;

   };
   #endif // IA_H
   ```

Comment: SO is not a code debugging service.

Comment: if you are suggesting, yes i did try debbuging the code, but i could not find a way to fix it, or find the bug in the logic

Comment: Please clearly indicate the line of code where the exception is thrown.

Comment: if i play X at 0,0 it crashes on the return of the best move 
`return jogadas.at(melhorMov); // return best move`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your vector is empty (as it should be, there are no remaining legal moves).

Calling `at(0)` on an empty vector throws an exception, because there is no element 0.

Comment: actually there is positions at 0 but you are right, i set the initial condition to -1 and made a verification on the return and other modifications and it worked, thanks for your help

Comment: @Ollegn: I'm not talking about position (0, 0) on the board, but index 0 in the vector.  When the vector is empty, 0 is not a legal index.

Comment: Im talking about the vectors, in c++ vectors starts at 0 and goes forth `Notice that the first element has a position of 0 (not 1).` [Font](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/vector/vector/at/)

Comment: @Ollegn: You missed my point.  Valid indexes have `i < size()`.  When `size() == 0`, then `0` is not a valid index.

Comment: oh, got it, it's true, the size counting starts at 1, if no data is stored in the vector the size is 0.

Comment: @Ollegn: Right.  `0` isn't a problem because of being too low (you are correct that indexing starts at `0` not `1`).  It's a problem because it is too high, when the vector is empty.